# Weird Display issue using iText 5

Tags: java, itext

I'm pretty sure the easiest answer to my problem is going to be "You need to update your version of iText." However, my boss is unwilling to update after updating from iText 4 to iText 5, as he put it, "Broke so much crap." So I'm using iText 5.0.1 to build this PDF.

I am building an application that will read in an Excel file and create badges for an event we take part of. It's fairly straightforward, and everything works as expected, except for the way the end result looks.

The way I have the PDF set up (code will be shown below) is that each badge is printed with a front and back (we print double sided), and each page itself is supposed to hold 6 badges. When I tested this by copying the same badge into each sell, it looked fine. But when I use a set of data, for whatever reason, my PDF is thrown off. Instead of 6 badges per page, it will *sometimes* print 6 per page, other times it'll print 3 per page. For example, my excel file has 21 lines of data - 21 badges to create. I get 3 sets of 3 badges per page, and 2 sets of 6 badges per page, set up as 3,6,6,3 respective to the number of badges on each page.

Is there something I am missing that would result in 3 pages of 6 badges each, followed by a page of just 3 badges?

```java
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, MARGIN, MARGIN, MARGIN, MARGIN);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
    document.open();
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    buildDocument(document, badgeFronts, badgeBacks);
    document.close();

    public void buildDocument(Document document, ArrayList<PdfPTable> badgeFronts, ArrayList<PdfPTable> badgeBacks) throws DocumentException{
        float[] frontTableWidths = {150f, 10f, 150f, 10f, 150f, 10f};
        float[] backTableWidths = {10f, 150f, 10f, 150f, 10f, 150f};
        PdfPTable frontTable = new PdfPTable(6);
        frontTable.setWidths(frontTableWidths);
        frontTable.setWidthPercentage(100);
        PdfPTable backTable = new PdfPTable(6);
        backTable.setWidths(backTableWidths);
        backTable.setWidthPercentage(100);
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < badgeFronts.size(); i++){
            PdfPCell frontCell = new PdfPCell();
            frontCell.setFixedHeight(260f);
            frontCell.setBorderColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
            PdfPCell backCell = new PdfPCell();
            backCell.setFixedHeight(260f);
            backCell.setBorderColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
            if(count == 5){
                count = 0;
                document.add(frontTable);
                document.newPage();
                document.add(backTable);
                document.newPage();
                frontTable.deleteBodyRows();
                backTable.deleteBodyRows();
            }
            PdfPTable front = badgeFronts.get(i);
            PdfPTable back = badgeBacks.get(i);
            frontCell.addElement(front);
            backCell.addElement(back);

            frontTable.addCell(frontCell);
            frontTable.addCell("");

            backTable.addCell("");
            backTable.addCell(backCell);

            if(i == badgeFronts.size() - 1){
                document.add(frontTable);
                document.newPage();
                document.add(backTable);
                document.newPage();
            }
            count++;
        }
        frontTable.completeRow();
        backTable.completeRow();
    }
```

Above is my code. I create the Tables that live in the main table's cells elsewhere and can show that if needed, however I don't believe it is necessary.

Comment: If you already switched to version 5 then try at least to use the latest version 5.5.X

Comment: @Lonzak Trust me, I'd like to. However my boss is very much in the mindset of "if it ain't broke, don't fix it!" with iText, so the chances of that happening are slim.

Comment: But why did you migrated from iText 4 (which in the java world didn't exist) to iText 5.0.1? 5.0 is AGPL licensed which means you have to buy a commercial license or you have to opensource your whole project. I am curious: Where can I find it? But if you have licensed it then you have commercial support and it doesn't matter if anything else brakes when you update to 5.5.X. If you don't pay then a migration to openPDF would have made much more sense...

Comment: @Lonzak If I had the answers I would share them with you. I've only been with the company for about a year and as far as I am aware they were already on iText 5.0.1 at that time.

Comment: So they did license it? Then contact commercial support from iText corp. If not please share the link to your AGPL licensed source code. Then the community can help...

Comment: iText Software employee here. @Lonzak is right. We can help you. Ask your boss for a login account on our support Jira. Assuming that your boss purchased a commercial license, including a support contract. If not, putting your project on a site like GitHub is probably the easiest way to comply with that part of the AGPL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
if(count == 5){
     count = 0;
     document.add(frontTable);
     document.newPage();
     document.add(backTable);
     document.newPage();
     frontTable.deleteBodyRows();
     backTable.deleteBodyRows();
}
```

This block of code is the issue. For starters, it's too early in the loop. It needs to be placed *after* the `count++;` statement. Second, instead of checking for `count == 5` after moving the block, checking for `count == 6` did the trick. As soon as this change happened, it started working exactly as it was expected to.

This pretty much means I'm not great at exhausting all my options before turning to Stack Overflow...